# Java program not outputing what I need it to

Tags: java

I need to write a code that :
A prime number is a positive integer greater than 1 that is divisible only by itself and 1. You are to write a program that repeatedly asks a user for an integer value and then displays all prime numbers less than or equal to that number.

Functional Requirements

The program will prompt the user for a positive number, or a value of -1 to end the program. If the user enters 0, or a negative number, the program will end immediately. Your program's behavior on input other than integers will not be tested.

The program will determine, for each number from 2 to the number given by the user, whether that number is prime or not. In the columnar format presented below, the program will display information about both prime and non-prime numbers.

When the table is complete the program will display the count of prime numbers in the given range and the ratio of prime numbers in the range.

Sample Run

```
Welcome to the prime number program!
########################################################
Please enter a positive integer: 6
Number    Is Prime  Counterexample
2         Yes       -
3         Yes       -
4         No        4 % 2 = 0
5         Yes       -
6         No        6 % 2 = 0
3 of the first 6 integers are prime; prime ratio = 0.5
```

So far, my program will only output:

```
Welcome to the prime number program!
########################################################
Please enter a positive integer: 2
```

my code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PrimeNumber
     {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the prime number program!");
            System.out.println("########################################################");
            Integer input=getInput(sc);
            if(input != null)
                { 
                    System.out.println("Number   Is Prime   Counterexample");
                    for(int l=2;l<l;l++)
                        {
                            int k=isPrime(l);
                            System.out.println(l+"\t"+(k==-1?"Yes\t\t"+"-":"No\t\t"+l+"%"+k+"=0"));
                        }
                    main(args);
                    return;
                }
            System.out.println("You Selected to exit ! Good Bye!");
        }

       public static int isPrime(int input)
        {
            for(int k=2;k<=input/2;k++)
                {
                    if(input%k==0)
                    {
                        return k;
                    }
                }
            return -1;
        }

       public static Integer getInput(Scanner sc)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: 2");
            String input=sc.next();
            Integer i;
            try
            {
            i=new Integer(input);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                i=input.chars().iterator().next();getInput(sc);
            }
            return i;
        }

       {



} }
```

Can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, in your `for` loop you have `l<l` as the condition.

Comment: This is a poster example for using meaningful variables names, and NEVER using lowercase `L` as a variable name (too similar to `1`).

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is never executed since `l` is never less than `l` itself. You need to loop from 2 till the number input by the user:

```
for(int l=2;l<input.intValue();l++)
```

Comment: This leaves me with the error message: the operator <= is unidentified for the argument type(s) int, Integer?

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of Java that doesn't support autoboxing and unboxing... Try the updated code.

Comment: This did not show up with an error, but it is still only coding:                                                          Welcome to the prime number program!
########################################################
Please enter a positive integer: 2

Comment: You are supposed to enter a number here.

Comment: Enter a number where exactly?